# How to start an exe from a .NET Windows Service for updating the service

Tags: c#, windows, uac

I have a windows service that I would like to be automatically and silently updated.  I started using wyBuild to implement this, but have had some issues with it, and decided to try to build my own.  I've written a standalone exe that can be called to do the update procedure:  checks for a new zip file with the update, downloads it, unzips, stop the windows service, copy files from the zip, then restart the service.  This exe works fine when I run it from the commandline and wasn't really difficult to write.

However, now I would like the service (the same one being updated) to shell out to the updater exe to update itself.  I first tried Process.Start:

```
var proc = Process.Start(pathToUpdaterExe);
proc.WaitForExit(60000);
```

This called the updater, but when the updater stops the service, the process is killed and the update stops.  I did some searching and it sounds like the solution is to use a separate AppDomain.  This is what I have now:

```
Evidence baseEvidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
Evidence objEvidence = new System.Security.Policy.Evidence(baseEvidence);
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
var updateDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("updateDomain", objEvidence, setup);
updateDomain.ExecuteAssembly(updater);
AppDomain.Unload(updateDomain);
```

However, now I get the error System.IO.IOException: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Service\Service.dll' because it is being used by another process" when attempting to copy over the new Service.dll

Again, I've *stopped* the service at this point.  I've confirmed this with logging.  I can't imagine what would have Service.dll still locked, so I added code to check to see what is locking it:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Process> GetProcessesLocking(string filePath)
    {
        var result = new List<Process>();

        result.Clear();
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            try
            {
                if (proc.HasExited) continue;
                foreach (ProcessModule module in proc.Modules)
                {
                    if ((module.FileName.ToLower().CompareTo(filePath.ToLower()) == 0))
                    {
                        result.Add(proc);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log(ex.ToString());
                Log("There was an error checking " + proc.ProcessName );
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

However this code indicates that nothing has a lock on the dll (result is empty and nothing is logged indicating an error).

I suspect I'm running afoul of some UAC issue that is the real cause of the IOException.  The windows service runs as LocalSystem.  All that to ask:  How *should* I be running the update exe from the windows service such that it has rights to copy files in c:\Program Files?

**Update**

As the comments and answer suggest, Process.Start can work, but there is some nuance.  You have to start cmd.exe and use *it* to start the updater.  I also found I could not use a full path for the updater exe and that I needed to set UseShellExecute=false.  This is my final working code that launches the updater from the .NET service:

```
 var cmd = "/c start updater.exe";     
 var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
 startInfo.Arguments = cmd;
 startInfo.WorkingDirectory = AssemblyDirectory;
 startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Completely off the top of my head, but why not just have the service create a scheduled task to start in 5 seconds time?  That way the process that initiates the update and the actual processing of the update are completely disconnected

Comment: When this happens, can look up the DLL name ("find handle") in Process Explorer to see who still has a handle open to the DLL? Or record such a session in Process Monitor. Just find the real culprit. You don't know whether starting 5 seconds later will be more successful.

Comment: Your 1st solution could work.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035213/process-start-and-the-process-tree to see how to keep the updater alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this exact thing - using a simpler (some might say kludgy) approach.  The service:

1. Produces a batch command,
2. Downloads the new executables to a staging location,
3. Starts a process: cmd.exe which, in turn, runs the batch script w/o waiting for it to complete, and then
4. Immediately terminates itself.

The batch command:

1. Pings 127.0.0.1 five times,
2. Copies the executables to the final location and,
3. Restarts the service.

Works like clockwork.  The ping is a reliable 5 second delay - lets the service shutdown before copying the files.

**Edit**:

Just for completeness - I realized that by batch cmd is pinging 127.0.0.1 not 128.0.0.1 and so I edited this answer to reflect that. I suppose either works - but 128.0.0.1 pings timeout, where 127.0.0.1 resolves to "me".  Since I'm only using it as a poor-man's delay, it serves the purpose either way.

Comment: It looks like using Process.Start with cmd.exe is key here. Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c updater.exe") does what I want.  My process is a bit different - instead of a batch it uses a .net console app, and the console app does the check for updates, stopping/starting the service, and applying update. There is some other nuance I ran into - I will update my question with the code I'm using.

Comment: Excellent - glad that worked for you.  Getting it cleanly out from your process makes it much easier.